# Does separation of variables of a transfer function followed by a z-domain transform work?

Tags: lowpass-filter, z-transform

I tried taking a low pass filter transfer function in the form $A/(s^2+Bs+C)$ and separating it into multiple fractions over each root $(D/(s+r1))+(E/(s+r2))$.

Then I substituted $s =((2/T)*((z-1)/(z+1)))$ to perform a z-transform. After I get a difference equation in the form $y[n] = F1*x[n] + G1*x[n-1] - H1*[y[n-1] + F2*x[n] + G2*x[n-1] - H2*[y[n-1] + ... + Fm*x[n] + Gm*x[n-1] - Hm*[y[n-1]$

If I would not have performed the separation of variables, I would have a second order difference equation. Instead, I got a first order difference equation.

My problem is when I try to filter a signal with the first order difference equation I get the wrong output. The wave magnitude gets very large for all the frequencies.

Here is the code I used to implement the equation. I know the transfer functions I get are right because I am using examples from Les Thede's book titled Practical Analog and Digital Filter Design. The complex number methods, separation of variables method, and root finder method are also tested.

```
public class LowPassFilter extends Filter{

    public LowPassFilter(double apass, double astop, double fpass, double fstop){
        this.apass = apass;
        this.astop = astop;
        this.fpass = fpass;
        this.fstop = fstop;
    }

    public double[] butterWorth(double[] wave, float sr) {
        double[] b = new double[wave.length];

        // Frequency Warp
        double k = (2.0*sr);
        double tp = 2.0*Math.PI;
        double fpass = k*(Math.tan(((this.fpass*tp)/k))); //k*Math.tan(this.fpass*tp/k);
        double fstop = k*(Math.tan(((this.fstop*tp)/k))); //k*Math.tan(this.fstop*tp/k);

        // Pass band gain adjustment factor
        double e = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(10, (-0.1*apass))-1.0);

        // Filter order
        int n = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log((
                Math.pow(10, -0.1*astop)-1.0)/(
                        Math.pow(10, (-0.1*apass))-1.0))/(2.0*
                                Math.log((fstop)/(fpass))));
        if(n < 1) {
            n = 1;
        }

        // Normalized circle radius
        double r = Math.pow(e, -1.0/n);

        // Angles
        double[] a;
        if(n%2 != 0) {
            a = new double[((n-1)/2)];
        } else {
            a = new double[(n/2)];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = Math.PI*(2.0*i+n+1.0)/(2.0*n);
        }

        // Adjacent and opposite
        double [] q = new double[a.length];
        double [] w = new double[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            q[i] = r*Math.cos(a[i]);
            w[i] = r*Math.sin(a[i]);
        }

        // For transfer function denominator s^2+b1s+b2 
        // except for odd order functions where the last in the arrays represent b1s+b2
        double[] b1;
        double[] b2;
        if(n%2 != 0) {
            b1 = new double[q.length+1]; 
            b2 = new double[q.length+1];
        } else {
            b1 = new double[q.length]; 
            b2 = new double[q.length];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b2.length; i++){
            if(i != q.length) {
                b1[i] = -2.0*q[i];
                b2[i] = Math.pow(q[i], 2.0)+Math.pow(w[i], 2.0);
            } else {
                b1[i] = 1;
                b2[i] = r;
            }
        }

        // Quality factors
        double[] qual = new double[b2.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < qual.length; i++){
            qual[i] = Math.sqrt(b2[i])/b1[i];
        }

        // Transfer function coefficients for the numerator and denominator
        ComplexNumber[] one = {new ComplexNumber(1)};
        ComplexMatrix num = new ComplexMatrix(one);
        double[] den1 = new double[b2.length];
        double[] den2 = new double[b2.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < b2.length; i++){
            num.mulRow(0, b2[i]);
            den1[i] = b1[i];
            den2[i] = b2[i];
        }

        // Find the roots of the denominator polynomials
        ComplexNumber[] tempRoots;
        ComplexNumber[] roots;
        if(n%2 == 0) {
            roots = new ComplexNumber[b2.length*2];
        } else if(n!= 1) {
            roots = new ComplexNumber[b2.length*2-1];
        } else {
            roots = new ComplexNumber[1];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b2.length; i++){
            if((i != ((roots.length-1)/2) || n%2 == 0) && n > 1) {
                tempRoots = Polynomial.QFC(1, den1[i], den2[i]);
                roots[2*i] = tempRoots[0];
                roots[2*i+1] = tempRoots[1];            
            }
        }
        if(n%2 != 0) {
            roots[roots.length-1] = new ComplexNumber(-den2[den2.length-1]);
        }

        // Separate the numerator over the roots into a sum of fractions with one numerator over one root
        ComplexNumber[] nums = Fractions.pfd(num.getRow(0), roots);

        // Calculate the difference equation coefficients using substitution s=s/fpass
        ComplexNumber[] xn = new ComplexNumber[nums.length];
        ComplexNumber[] xn1 = new ComplexNumber[nums.length];
        ComplexNumber[] yn1 = new ComplexNumber[nums.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            xn[i] = ComplexNumber.div(
                    ComplexNumber.mul(nums[i], fpass), (
                            ComplexNumber.add(
                                    ComplexNumber.mul(
                                            ComplexNumber.mul(roots[i], -1), fpass), k)));
            xn1[i] = xn[i];
            yn1[i] = ComplexNumber.div(
                    ComplexNumber.add(
                            ComplexNumber.mul(
                                    ComplexNumber.mul(roots[i], -1), fpass), -k),
                    ComplexNumber.add(
                            ComplexNumber.mul(
                                    ComplexNumber.mul(roots[i], -1), fpass), k));
        }
        ComplexNumber xnt = new ComplexNumber(0);
        ComplexNumber xn1t = new ComplexNumber(0);
        ComplexNumber yn1t = new ComplexNumber(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < xn.length; i++){
            xnt = ComplexNumber.add(xnt, xn[i]);
            xn1t = ComplexNumber.add(xn1t, xn1[i]);
            yn1t = ComplexNumber.add(yn1t, yn1[i]);
        }

        // Filter the wave
        b[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < wave.length; i++){
            b[i] = ComplexNumber.mul(xnt, wave[i]).getReal()+
                    ComplexNumber.mul(xn1t, wave[i-1]).getReal()-
                    ComplexNumber.mul(yn1t, b[i-1]).getReal();
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Do I need to use second order equations when making the difference equation?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a first order difference equation in the separated case? Namely you should still need to add two first order discrete transfer functions with different denominators, which can only be combined into one transfer function of order two.

Comment: In the second order case, I get two first order fractions that are added together. Then I add the first order difference equations, which becomes $y[n]=(F1+F2)*x[n]+(G1+G2)*x[n-1]+(H1+H2)*y[n-1]$

Comment: you can't just add the filter coefficients of both first order filters to combine them. Namely each (first order) filter has its own output $y_i[n]$.

Comment: Does $y[n] = y1[n] + y2[n]$?

Comment: Yes, but if $$y_i[n]=F_i\,x[n]+G_i\,x[n-1]+H_i\,y_i[n-1]$$ then $$y[n]=(F_1+F_2)\,x[n]+(G_1+G_2)\,x[n-1]+H_1\,y_1[n-1]+H_2\,y_2[n-1].$$ this is only equal to your equation if $$H_1\,y_1[n]+H_2\,y_2[n]=(H_1+H_2)\,(y_1[n]+y_2[n]),$$ which is only the case when $H_1=H_2$ (so when both first order poles are the same).

Comment: $h(s)=(a/(s+r1)+(b/(s+r2)))$ is the transfer function. Both fractions can be represented with difference equations $y_i[n]=F_i\,x[n]+G_i\,x[n-1]+H_i\,y_i[n-1]$. Just to be clear, you are saying they can't be added unless $H_i is the same in each case, meaning the roots are the same?

Comment: In my implementation, I do have the final fraction of each difference equations as $y[n]=(a/(k+r_i))*x[n]+(a/(k+r_i))*x[n-1]+((r_i-k)/(r_i+k))*y[n-1]

Comment: My remark in my previous comment (when both first order poles are the same) is indeed referring to the roots of the denominators of the two discrete first order transfer functions, which have the roots $z_i=H_i$.